# How to check the active number of consumers in a consumer group using kafka-python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a consumer group with 15 consumers in it. When I start the process, around 200 records are processed by these 15 consumers in one minute, but later on as the number of incoming records goes down, I believe consumers start losing connection after being idle for 540000ms .

I want to see how many consumers are still active in a particular consumer group using kafka-python, so that I can add consumers to keep the processing going on. The same can be done using --member command in shell but I'm interested in doing it in kafka-python.

Comment: I don't think you can find this with that library. You'd need to `Popen(["kafka-consumer-groups.sh"...`

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer I have never used this library, Could you please create a command for me. That will be very helpful me.

Comment: Like I said, `kafka-python` doesn't have this function/command. You'll need to use the shell scripts like you've mentioned from python